# Kate "tab-spacing character" removal or turn-off

Tags: tabs, character, indentation, kate

I am using Kate Text Editor for Linux Mint 14. I was wondering if there is any way to remove tab spacing?

I mean where ever there is a tab-indent, there is a character `>>` which doesn't  look good while editing and is even quite confusing (Please refer screenshot). Is there an option to delete it?

[image: screenshot]

I could not find any option relating to this in the configurations and settings.

Answer (score 10):

I have an option for this in Kate version 3.6.5:

Go to: `Settings` - `Configure Kate` - `Editor component` - `Appearance`
and disable `Highlight tabulators`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using Kate 21.12.3 with British English, this setting has a different name from the answers above.

Settings > Configure Kate... > Appearance > General > **Show tab indicators**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My version of Kate had it at Configure Kate - Appearance - General - Highlight tabulators.

Comment: Please include the version of Kate and OS you're using.